# embed a button into an excel chart

Tags: c#, excel, charts, vsto

Roughly speaking, I want to create a child class from Excel Chart to add the following features into the child:

1. add a button to the visual appearance of the chart (the button should have a fixed position relatively to the chart - so if I move chart, the button moves as well). Actually, it doesn't have to be exactly button - it may be anything else which allows clicking on it (or do any other action) and do some activities after the click.
2. add some additional properties to the chart (these properties doesn't appear vizually but they influence the representation of the time-series). Maybe there is a standard way to customize the set of the properties of Excel Chart?

I don't know to what extent it is possible. Maybe "child class" is not that good idea to serve such simple needs. Maybe VSTO has something, but I can't find anything suitable in the Internet.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

PS

For the subquestion #2 I've decided to use the field TAG to put there an object with additional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question it is possible to embed a form-control button or a shape in a chart, and have it keep its position relative to the chart area, by cutting and pasting it onto the chart. Use the `OnAction` property to assign a procedure to the button.

Recorded code (in Excel) is like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(166.5, 48, 48, 32.25).Select
    Selection.OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!TestMacro"
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 10
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 30
End Sub
```

It may be possibly to do this programmatically without cutting and pasting, perhaps by adding to the ChartObject's ShapeRange, but I haven't explored this.

I do not know to what extent you can directly subclass an Excel Chart (if at all) and suspect that you might just create a wrapper class for it in C#.

Comment: I understand it is possible to subclass Excel objects, with the help of Win32 API calls, but I notice a lot of people encountering problems when attempting to do this: just a heads up!

Comment: Andrew, thanks a lot - it really helps regarding the first part of the question! Hope to convert it into c#.

Comment: Maybe the object model of Chart has a property with "object" type where I can put my externally created object with all the aditional information that I wanted to put into the child class? I mean a property that is not used or rarely used.

Comment: You are welcome. This page http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SubclassingWithSSubTmr6.htm discusses subclassing in Excel, and some of the problems encountered.

Comment: Could you please share your idea how to recognize the Chart from inside the OnAction of the button? I mean, in my application I'll have tens of thse pairs "button+chart".

Comment: Assuming you obtain a reference to the button you could examine its Parent property to identify the chart. The action would be a simple procedure (macro), not an event procedure, so you wouldn't have "this" to help identify the button.  Note, ActiveX buttons can also be cut and pasted onto the chart area, but form controls or shapes are much simpler objects and don't have referenced dlls (ocx's) to worry about. I would stick with a simple button or shape.